# Installation problem "serious problem couldnt find mok"

Tags: dual-boot, surface-tablet

I tried to install Elementary OS alongside windows 10.

I created a bootable disk with Rufus. I know that the disk works because I could manage to install it to my old thinkpad. But when I tried to install it on my **Surface**, I made a mistake and tried the option to create a partition and did something wrong.

When I tried to restart the pc did not open and gave me "something went seriously wrong, could not find mok" ( I am not sure if I am writing this correct the screen goes too quick). I took it to a repair guy, he installed the Windows 10 back again and windows works now. But my C/ drive shows only 99 something and there is a new D/ drive showing 18 something. I think this is because I tried to create a 20000 mb partition and this was wrong.

Now my surface won't boot from USB and gives me the same error. I can start windows. I don't know how to solve this problem and did not see anyone facing a similar problem. I am new to Linux and not really good with computers.

So I would be glad if someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: the error is it `Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed` ?

Comment: Yes that's the error code ✌️

Comment: And what is 8 *something* and 99 *something* ? I think the person who reinstalled Windows 10 used the largest partition. And what is the Surface model where you want to install elementary OS? In addition, a bootable USB stick can work on one computer but not on another, because one supports the UEFI the other no and for other raisson

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I solved the problem by going to the EFI folder of the bootable disk and change the boot x64 to mmx.efi and the problem was solved ✌️

Comment: Maybe you can Aswer your question by yourself with all your proceess, maybe that help other peoples